# Apply products list template in a custom module prestashop 1.7

Tags: module, prestashop

I create a custom module in prestashop 1.7, and I would like to apply the layout of products list on my module and display products what I want. What I have to do ?

My initContent function is

```
class TestModuleDisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController{

    public function initContent()
    {
       parent::initContent();
       $this->setTemplate('products.tpl');
    }
}
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Hi Varag and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Your answer is here waiting for you : https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/

For instance your function must look like that :

```
  public function initContent()
  {
    // In the template, we need the vars paymentId & paymentStatus to be defined
    $this->context->smarty->assign(
    array(
      'paymentId' => Tools::getValue('id'), // Retrieved from GET vars
    ));

   // Will use the file modules/cheque/views/templates/front/validation.tpl
   $this->setTemplate('module:cheque/views/templates/front/validation.tpl');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to use array instead of object:

```
$listing['products'] = json_decode(json_encode($your_products), true); // convert object to array
$this->context->smarty->assign("listing", $listing);
$this->setTemplate('module:mymodule/views/templates/front/mytemplate.tpl');
```